# How to solve this nonlinear wave-like equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

The equation has a form as:
$$ \frac{d^2 q}{dt^2} + f(t) q = g(t) $$

The concrete equation is :
$$ 1.61504 \frac{d^2 q}{dt^2} + (13.6833 + 0.312247 \dot{\theta}^2)q= 7.34943 \ddot{\theta} $$
$$ \dot{\theta}= \frac{4}{15}t - \frac{4}{2\pi}\sin(\frac{2\pi}{15}t)  $$
I have seen some papers about solution to nonlinear wave-like eqaution. But I don't get the solution.

If you can solve it or have read papers or websites about the solution including numerical solution, please help me.

Comment: Which "papers" are you referring to? Perhaps if you linked us to some of them we could explain the details to you.

Comment: I'm sorry for not expressing the meaning correctly. In fact, I have seen paper about  solution towave-like equations, different from this equation. I have not seen the same form as my question.

Comment: Sorry, is this a differential equation to solve in $q$ or in $\theta$. The form indicates $q$, but the solution given indicates $\theta$.

Comment: I want to get the concrete solution of q. Obviously the $ \theta $ can easy get without considering the wave-like equation.

Comment: Fourier Transform might help

Comment: As you've presented it, this is linear in $q.$ Why are you saying it's nonlinear?

Comment: I'm afraid you have read it wrong. @Adrian Keister [the definition of linear equation in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation)

Comment: @HIDEENICE You linked to the definition of a linear equation. But that is certainly not what you have here: you have a *differential* equation. And it is linear in $q$ as you've presented it. Here is the correct link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation.

Comment: @Adrian Keister Woo! I get it. Thanks for the problem pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried numerical solution by using ode45 functionin MATLAB. Aha. Maybe it dosen't have analytical solution. Awww！

Here is the MATALB code:

```
tspan = [0,15];
y0 = [0,0.01];
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) odefun(t,y),tspan,y0);
plot(t,y(:,1),'-o',t,y(:,2),'-.')
plot(t,y(:,1))

function dydt = odefun(t,y)
dydt = zeros(2,1);
dydt(1) = y(2);
dydt(2) = 1.21349 - 1.21349 *cos(2*pi*t/15)-( 8.5116 + 0.0137484*t^2 - 0.0391781*cos((4 *pi* t)/15) - 0.0656436*t*sin(2 *pi* t)/15)*y(1);
end
```

[The solution of q (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVj9h.png)

Comment: I think you're correct that this DE does not have an analytical solution. You could probably slog through a series solution.

Comment: @AdrianKeister  Hmm. Thanks!  But I will stop trying to get analytical solution. I plan to do use numerical fitting using the numerical solution.  I think my research problem will be well solved by this way.